# Codeigniter missing argument

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am learning codeigniter. I am trying to show the all posts. On clicking the post title it takes to the respective post. 

View to display all posts **post_index.php**:

```
foreach ($posts as $post) { ?>
<div id-="container">
    <div><h3><a href="<?php base_url(); ?>posts/post/<?php $post['postID']; ?>"><?php echo $post['title']; ?> </a></h3>
        <?php echo $post['post']; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
}
```

Controller **posts.php**

```
<?php
class Posts extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('post');
    }
    function index(){
        $data['posts'] = $this->post->get_posts();
        $this->load->view('post_index', $data);
    }

    function post($postid){
        $data['post']=$this->post->get_post($postid);
        $this->load->view('post',$data);
    }
```

Model **post.php**

```
class Post extends CI_Model{
    function get_posts($num=20, $start=0){
        $this->db->select()->from('posts')->where('active',1)->order_by('date_added','desc')->limit($num,$start);
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    function get_post($postid){
        $this->db->select()->from('posts')->where(array('active' => 1, 'postID'=>$postid))->order_by('date_added','desc');
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->first_row('array');
    }
```

Displaying all the posts is fine. On click the single post, I get the following errors

> **A PHP Error was encountered**
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Missing argument 1 for Posts::post()
>
> Filename: controllers/posts.php
>
> Line Number: 12
>
> **A PHP Error was encountered**
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: postid
>
> Filename: controllers/posts.php
>
> Line Number: 13
>
> **A PHP Error was encountered**
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: title
>
> Filename: views/post.php
>
> Line Number: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the echo in your view.

```
<?php echo $post['postID']; ?>
```

You can also simplify it :

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url("posts/post/".$post['postID']); ?>">
```

Comment: Instead of using echo all the time you can always do `<?=$variable ?>`

Comment: Yes but for that he must enable short tags in is config which I am not sure of